# recursion with creating unique combinations

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write function that will be adding unique combinations to the list from given number.
For example when input = 3 I expect list with 123, 132, 213, 231 ... etc elements

```
resultss = []

def fun(number, result=''):
    if len(result) == number:
        return resultss.append(result)
    else:
        for x in range(1, number + 1):
           if str(x) not in result:
               result += str(x)
               return fun(number, result)

fun(4)
print(resultss)
```

The problem is, this function adds only first combination 1234 for 4 for example.
Any solution?

Comment: As soon as you `return`, the `for` loop is over...

Comment: Is the same effect for while loop?

Comment: Of course. The whole *function* is over once you hit `return`.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise, `itertools` can do this for you

Comment: if it is an exercise then just remove the `return` statements all together, `resultss.append(..)` returns `None` so recursive calls will also return `None` so your function isn't returning anything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated above, in case this is not just a recursion exercise, you can do it using itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations


def fun(number):
    return [''.join(p)
            for p in permutations([str(n) for n in range(1, number)])]
```